# Testing ViewHistory in Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, karma-runner, chai

I have a very simple app showing a login screen and a dashboard. When the login is successful the app navigates to the dashboard.

In this state, a back navigation (android) should not go back to the login screen.

This all works fine using the IonicHistory

```
this.$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
  disableBack: true
});

return this.$state.go("dashboard");
```

This is all done in my LoginCtrl when the SessionService (which does the login call to the service and the Session management...) resolves the returned promise.

Now I want to write a Unit-Test to check this behaviour and make sure, never every removes this nextViewOptions-call.

My idea is something like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module("ionic");
    angular.mock.module("myapp");

    inject(function ($q: IQService, $rootScope: IScope, $ionicHistory: IonicHistoryService): void {
        qService = $q;
        scope = $rootScope;
        ionicHistory = $ionicHistory;
    });
});

describe("login", () => {
    // Stub my sessionservice to immediatly resolve instead of doing a request
    sinon.stub(sessionService, "login", () => qService.when());

    let loginCtrl: LoginCtrl = new LoginCtrl(sessionService, stateService, ionicHistory);
    loginCtrl.executeLogin();

    scope.$apply();

    // Here I want to validate, that the history (and therefore the back-stack) is correct. 
    // But the ionicHistory.viewHistory() does not change at all. 
    // Independent whether I add the nextViewOptions stuff or not...
}
```

Here the output from ionichHistory.viewHistory().histories:

```
Object{root: Object{historyId: 'root', parentHistoryId: null, stack: [], cursor: -1}}
```

I use the karma test runner to execute the tests.

I'm using:

- Ionic 1.3.0
- Karama Test Runner
- TypeScript

Is this actually possible at all? Do I miss something completely?